# Case sensitivity in SQLite syntax

Tags: sql, sqlite, case-sensitive

does select statement in SQLite is case sensitive ?
I mean is there any problem writing one of the two following requests :

```
select * from Demand where Id_Demand = x
```

and :

```
select * from demand where id_demand = x
```

Is this configurable within SQLite RDBMS ?

Answer (score 1):

SQL keywords and indentifiers are case insensitive. There's no functional difference in your two queries.

From convention point of view, keywords are often written in ALL CAPS and identifiers in all lowercase, for example

```
SELECT * FROM demand WHERE id_demand = x
```

Also worth noting that some database wrapper libraries treate identifiers as case sensitive. For example, Android sqlite Cursor `getColumnIndex()` is case sensitive.